# Trocar ícone com clique no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Consegui fazer desta forma, mas fica a questão será que tem uma forma melhor de fazer? Galera, dicas e sugestões são muito bem vindas Obrigado.

```
document.querySelector('#menu-opener').addEventListener('click', trocarIcone);

function trocarIcone(){    
    let troca = document.querySelector('#menu-opener');
    if(troca.classList.contains('img01')==true){
        troca.classList.toggle('img02');        
    }else {
        troca.classList.toggle('img01');       
    }
    
}
```

Comment: De forma nativa acho que seria isso mesmo, não sei o seu objetivo, mas você poderia pegar como referencia o funcionamento de collapse [link](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/)

Comment: Depende do que vc chama "melhor". Algo pode parecer "melhor" pra um mas não pra outro. Se minimizar o código parecer melhor, daria pra usar um ternário: `troca.classList.toggle('img0' + troca.classList.contains('img01') ? '2' : '1');`.

Comment: vlw brother, vou testar aqui

Answer (score 1):

Oi, não sou o melhor mas tem algumas coisas que tem como melhorar

```
let troca = document.querySelector('#menu-opener')
troca.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(troca.classList.contains('img01')){
        troca.classList.toggle('img02')
    }else{
        troca.classList.toggle('img01');
    }
})
```

Se você quiser, acho que tem alguma forma de fazer a alteração da imagem sem usar o if else, mas não tenho certeza. :)